# how to multiply batch of matrices by corresponding tensors (1 D) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

suppose I have tensor of shape (3,2,2), and I want to multiply each (2,2) matrix by some 1d tensor. here is code:

```
a=tf.constant([[[1,0],[1,0]], [[2,0],[1,0]], [[3,0],[1,0]] ])
b=tf.constant([1,2,3])
```

here i want to multiply `[[1,0],[1,0]]` by 1, `[[2,0],[1,0]]` by 2 and `[[3,0],[1,0]]` by 3. so after multiplication i should get:

```
[[[1,0],[1,0]], [[4,0],[2,0]], [[9,0],[3,0]] ]
```

edit: i am not using eager execution

Comment: hello, i solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.multiply(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b)])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],
       [[4, 0],
        [2, 0]],
       [[9, 0],
        [3, 0]]])>
```

Comment: i already found different answer, and better one, thanks anyway

Comment: I'm flattered. Why don't you post it as an answer so everyone knows you're not awaiting an answer anymore

Comment: sorry your solution is not working neither mine. like i said i am not using eager execution. at first i had loop(it is easy one), i don't want to have loop

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: isn't that in the question? i gave detailed question, i think there can't be more detailed answer

Comment: an example that isn't eager execution

Comment: I don't know how to describe problem in graph mode. i am still begginer and don't understand tensorflow fully. So that was the problem that i didn't understand